# power query - how to use a filtered list of an sql query

Tags: filter, powerquery

i have an sql query which selects a list of data.

but i want to use this data after filtering it in excel table (not in power query)

i tried to create another "query from table" but it takes all the data, not the filtered one.

[Example File](https://cloud.mail.ru/public/KjMz/Cxvtdjp6Y)

any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you filter the table in Excel, it will only **hide** the rows that do not meet the selection criteria, it will not **delete** the rows.

In order to get a filtered table, you can create a separate table with filter criteria and use that to create a filtered table, either by using Advanced Filtering in Excel, or by using Power Query.

In [this video](https://youtu.be/i9DxNHZ3mGY) I illustrate how to do it with Advanced Filtering.

Comment: thank you for Advanced Filtering video... i'd better prefer to use Power Query option cause i cannot refresh the advanced filter every time w/o any macro.

Comment: @UmutK did this answer your question? (If so, make sure to mark it as the correct answer!) It seems you need to use Power Query to filter the original table so that your next query can start with the right data.

Comment: @marcelbeug actually, it's not the exact answer i was looking for , though it shows another way around... thanks for your time and effort...